# Assign char address to an int pointer, and consequently write an int-size piece of memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, dereference

from the book *Stroustrup - Programming: Principles and practices using C++*. In *§17.3*, about *Memory, addresses and pointers*, **it is supposed to be allowed** to assign a `char*` to `int*`:

```cpp
char ch1 = 'a';
char ch2 = 'b';
char ch3 = 'c';
char ch4 = 'd';
int* pi = &ch3;   // point to ch3, a char-size piece of memory
*pi = 12345;      // write to an int-size piece of memory
*pi = 67890;
```

graphically we have something like this:

[image: char address to int pointer]

quoting from the source:

> Had the compiler allowed the code, we would have been writing `12345` to the memory starting at `&ch3`. That would definitely have changed the value of some nearby memory, such as `ch2` or `ch4`, or we would have overwritten part of `pi` itself.

> In that case, the next assignment `*pi = 67890` would place `67890` in some completely different part of memory.

---

I don't understand, why the next assignment would place it: *in some completely different part of memory*? The address stored in `int *pi` is still `&ch3`, so that assignment would be overwrite the content at that address, i.e. `12345`. Why it isn't so?

Please, can you help me? Many thanks!

Comment: `&ch3` results in a `char*` not a `int*` so that assignment is illegal without for example a `reinterpret_cast` which I wouldn't do. But I think their point is that if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` then writing to `pi` will write past the allocated memory of `ch3`, all the way up to the first few bytes of `pi` itself (see the diagram. Therefore the next derefence will be some other address since `pi` pointer itself was modified accidentally.

Comment: This is simply an example of what happens when [demons fly out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon). The first assignment clobbers (partially) the value of `pi` itself.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be... unnatural

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the book uses C++11 and C++14.

Comment: @JB-Franco I've removed the C tag then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char ch3 = 'c';
int* pi = &ch3;
```

> it is supposed to be allowed to assign a char* to int*:

Not quite - there is an alignment concern.  It is *undefined behavior* (UB) when

> If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 6.3.2.3 7

Example: Some processor require `int *` to be even and if `&ch3` was odd, storing the address *might* fail, and de-referencing the address certainly fails: [bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Unaligned_access).

---

The next is certainly UB as the destination is outside the memory of `ch3`.
`ch1, ch2, ch4` might be nearby and provide some reasonable *undefined behavior*, but the result is UB.

```
// undefined behavior
*pi = 12345;      // write to an int-size piece of memory`
```

When code attempts to write outside its bounds - it is UB, anything may happen, including writing into neighboring data.

> The address stored in int *pi is still &ch3

Maybe, maybe not. UB has occurred.

> why the next assignment would place it: in some completely different part of memory?

The abusive code suggests that `pi` itself is overwritten by `*pi = 12345;`.   This might happen, it might not.  It is UB. A subsequent use of `*pi` is simply more UB.

---

Recall with UB you might get what you hope for, you might not - it is not defined by C.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have skipped part of the explanation you quoted:

> or we would have overwritten part of pi itself

Think of it this way, since `int`s are larger than `char`s, if an `int*` points to an address location that stores a `char`, there will be overflowing memory when you attempt to assign an integer value to that location, as you only have a single byte of memory allocated but are assigning 4 bytes worth of data. i.e. you cannot fit 4 bytes of data into one, so the other 3 bytes will go somewhere.

Assume then that the overflowing bytes partially change the value stored in `pi`. Now the next assignment will go to a random memory location.

Comment: > Assume then that the overflowing bytes partially change the value stored in ```pi```.

- Therefore the address stored within, will be corrupted.

> Now the next assignment will go to a random memory location.

- If the ```*pi``` can't resolve the above address because it is corrupted, the content will be inserted in a new address provided by the compiler. Is it correct?

Comment: No it is not. Addresses are just numbers, so as an analogy let's say the original address in pi was 125 smith street. Let's say the overflow corrupts pi, thus changing it to say 349 smith street. If you go to the new address, you may end up anywhere, including outside of the city.

In actual terms assume `pi = 8864`, the overflow corrupts that value, changing it to some random value, say `pi = 4264`. Then the next time you are writing to pi you are writing to the modified address, which is a random value.

Comment: @JB-Franco "Now the next assignment will go to a random memory location. " is not specified by C.  The compiler need not re-read `pi` and instead use the same pointer value.  The there is much undefined behavior here.

Comment: Take into account the reply must be framed by what the texts in OP's answer say. The question is how or why it will go to a random location, so we must assume this is a case where the compiler does reread pi.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the memory address layout is:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

From the left 0, 1, 2 and 3 are characters. From the right 4, 5, 6 and 7 are an int*.
The values in each byte in hex may be:

```
61 62 63 64 02 00 00 00
```

Note how the first four are ascii values and the last four are the address of `ch3`. Writing `*pi = 12345;` Changes the values like so:

```
61 62 39 30 00 00 00 00
```

With `0x39300000` being 12345 in little endian hexadecimal.

The next write `*pi = 67890;` would start from memory adress `00 00 00 00` not `02 00 00 00` as one could expect.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to understand that everything is a number i.e., a `char`, `int`, `int*` all contain numbers. Memory addresses are also numbers. Let's assume the current example compiles and we have memory like following:

```
--------------------------
Address | Variable | Value
--------------------------
0x01   |    ch1       a
0x02   |    ch2       b
0x03   |    ch3       c
0x04   |    ch4       d
0x05   |    pi        &ch3 = 0x03
```

Now let's dereference `pi` and reassign  a new value to `ch3`:

```
*pi = 12345;
```

Let's assume `int` is 4 bytes. Since `pi` is an `int` pointer, it will write a 4 byte value to the location pointed by `pi`. Now, `char` can only contain one byte values so, what would happen if we try to write 4 bytes to that location? Strictly speaking, this is undefined behaviour but I will try to explain what the author means.

Since `char` cannot contain values larger than 1 byte, `*pi = 12345` will overflow `ch3`. When this overflow happens, the remaining 3 bytes out of the 4 bytes may get written in the memory location nearby. What memory locations do we have nearby? `ch4` and `pi` itself! `ch4` can only contain 1 byte as well, that leaves us with 2 bytes and the next location is `pi` itself. Meaning `pi` will overwrite it's own value!

```
--------------------------
Address | Variable | Value
--------------------------
0x01   |    ch1       a
0x02   |    ch2       b
0x03   |    ch3       12  //12 ended up here
0x04   |    ch4       34  //34 ended up here
0x05   |    pi        &ch3 = 0x03 // 5 gets written here
```

As you can see that `pi` is now pointing to some other memory address which is definitely not `ch3`.

Comment: Good explanation, but one minor point -- `*pi = 12345` is assigning a decimal value, and you are breaking it into `12`, `34`, `5` as if it were hex

Comment: @Human-Compiler I know, but just making a point and being lazy lol.